# Set Division example in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms, not-exists

I know there is no set division in MySql but it can be attained using several ways as listed in [Divided we stand The SQL of relational division"](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

But I want to understand the first example in the article, it selects all the pilot_name from PilotSkills who can fly all the plane_name from Hangar

```
SELECT DISTINCT pilot_name 
FROM PilotSkills AS PS1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM Hangar
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                  FROM PilotSkills AS PS2
                 WHERE (PS1.pilot_name = PS2.pilot_name)
                   AND (PS2.plane_name = Hangar.plane_name)));
```

Can someone help me understanding it?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is but if you read carefully it says _if a pilot can fly more planes than just those we have in the hangar_ - so it selecting pilots who can fly planes NOT in the hangar.

Comment: I think the author mentioned this in the article:
We have a table of pilots and the planes they can fly (dividend); we have a table of planes in the hangar (divisor); we want the names of the pilots who can fly every plane (quotient) in the hangar.  To get this result, we divide the PilotSkills table by the planes in the hangar.